Is there a good way to Link CGAL in D?
I am trying to use CGAL in a D Program. I have generated the .o files from C++, but I am now stuck on how to link CGAL.
Because of this I would guess I need to find something similar to -lc++ but since CGAL is usually compiled with CMAKE I am not sure how to find this.
What I have compiled is similar to this (basically from here):
test.cpp
    
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
 
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/create_offset_polygons_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Straight_skeleton_2/IO/print.h>
 
#include <memory>
 
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
 
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K ;
 
typedef K::FT                        FT ;
typedef K::Point_2                   Point ;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K>           Polygon_2 ;
typedef CGAL::Straight_skeleton_2<K> Ss ;
 
typedef std::shared_ptr<Polygon_2> PolygonPtr ;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Ss> SsPtr ;
 
typedef std::vector<PolygonPtr> PolygonPtrVector ;
 
void test()
{
  Polygon_2 poly ;
 
  poly.push_back( Point(-1,-1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(0,-12) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(1,-1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(12,0) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(1,1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(0,12) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(-1,1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(-12,0) ) ;
 
  assert(poly.is_counterclockwise_oriented());
 
  FT lOffset = 1 ;
 
  PolygonPtrVector inner_offset_polygons = CGAL::create_interior_skeleton_and_offset_polygons_2(lOffset,poly);
  PolygonPtrVector outer_offset_polygons = CGAL::create_exterior_skeleton_and_offset_polygons_2(lOffset,poly);
 
  CGAL::Straight_skeletons_2::IO::print_polygons(inner_offset_polygons);
  CGAL::Straight_skeletons_2::IO::print_polygons(outer_offset_polygons);
 
}

int main() {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I am now trying to use this in my D Program like this:
test.d
extern (C++) void test();

void main() {
    test();
}

I would assume this would work similar to:
dmd test.d ./CGAL_skeleton/CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -L-lstdc++ 

as described here. But this still needs to link CGAL (I would assume)
Edit:
This can be fixed by removing the main function from the cpp file, and also link the files from /CMakeFiles/test.dir/link.txt.
This allows the code to run, but during the CGAL compile step the linker cannot create / link the executeable as there is no main function.
The call would look something like this:
dmd test.d ./CGAL_skeleton/CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -L-lstdc++  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so

Prepending -L before the files that are to be linked can randomly solve this but this is not reliable

1 minute research reveals: How to use CGAL with CMake, is that of help ??

No, i have already generated an object file with CGAL. I am now trying to use this in my D program. I am not sure how to link this from the D side.

Can you include a [mre], so any one with(out) basic knowledge of d and cmake can reproduce your problem?

I managed to fix this. The main issues were the following: Remove the main function from the cpp file, and also link the files in /CMakeFiles/test.dir/link.txt. This allows the code to run, but during the CGAL compile step the linker cannot create / link the executeable as there is no main function. I don't need it and the Object File is still created, but this may be an issue for others

"but this may be an issue for others"  Please [edit] the question to make it possible for others to answer that issue.

Use dmd -c to generate object file, and then use linker explicitly to link everything together with -lstdc++ -l gmpxx -lmpfr ...
